# Problems editing geometry in JS script using a find task in a web application

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wfs-t, dojo

I've generated a javascript code to my app based on the sample "Show find task results in a DataGrid" of ArcGIS API for JavaScript and I am using editable layers (WFS-T) and it works, but when after use it I try to select the data to change the geometry and edit it only allows to me edit the attributes, but I can't select the vertexs/nodes of the geometry by double-clicking.

This trouble only appears when I make a search, but not before use it.

How can I make my data editable again?

I've eliminated the graphics with map.graphics.hide() that I've generated before for the query and to store the data on the grid, and it works, but I've the problem with editing geometries.

If anyone can help me it would be very helpful! Thanks

Comment: Can you post some codes?

Comment: If I push the hide button, I can't edit other layers I've on the map and if I push later the Show button, editing is possible again. What is happen here? I need all time the layers in editing status.

Comment: <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button"  onClick="map.graphics.hide();""editorWidget.startup();">
       Hide selection
       </button>
       <button data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button"  onClick="map.graphics.show();">
       Show selection
       </button>

Comment: remove the inverted comma between hide and editor, it should look like onClick="map.graphics.hide();editorWidget.startup();"

Comment: No, It don't work! I tried to sturtup the editorwidget, but it's not a solution... maybe I need to write some other function or sentence but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

remove the inverted comma between hide and editor, it should look like

```
onClick="map.graphics.hide();editorWidget.startup();"
```

also the show button should be like

```
onClick="map.graphics.show();editorWidget.startup();"
```